# SignalR not serializing/deserializing custom DataMember name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working on a project and trying to integrate SignalR into it. I have a class with a data contract which allows me to use an underscore separated format on my client, and standard Pascal Case on the server, something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo {

    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    FirstName { get;set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    LastName { get;set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "phone")]
    Phone { get;set; }
}
```

This works fine when passing data through a fetch command to the Razor Page OnGet and OnPost methods, but does not work when using SignalR.

When sending data to server via SignalR, `first_name` and `last_name` are null, while `phone` gets sent correctly.

How can I make SignalR respect the `DataMember` Name when serializing/deserializing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson` package and adding the following in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddSignalR()
        .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol();
```

Comment: This answer should be marked correct. Could not figure out how to get my models to serialize correctly until I followed your steps here.

Answer (score 0):

The fields are not being serialized because their serialization attributes (`[DataMember]`) are not compatible with SignalR's default serialization engine (`System.Text.Json`).

One possible solution is to switch the serialization engine to Newtonsoft's JSON implementation, as suggested in @Aleksandr Albert's answer. Another solution is to use `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIncludeAttribute` instead, e.g.

```
public class Foo {
    [JsonPropertyName("first_name")]
    [JsonInclude]
    FirstName { get;set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("last_name")]
    [JsonInclude]
    LastName { get;set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("phone")]
    [JsonInclude]
    Phone { get;set; }
}
```

Each solution is (in)compatible with one of the serialization engines.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose currently you are sending the data as an object, somehow like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
_hub.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("ReceiveMessage", foo);
```

What I suggest is that you create the JSON by hand on the server side and send that, because you have better controll over the property names that way.

Add the `JsonProperty` attribute to the `Foo` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo {

    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    FirstName { get;set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    LastName { get;set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "phone")]
    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    Phone { get;set; }
}
```

And when you send the message, send the JSON string instead of letting SinglaR parse your object:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
_hub.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("ReceiveMessage", json);
```

Comment: Hey, the requests are being sent to server as a javascript object from a javascript client using `connection.invoke(...)`. I tried adding the JsonProperty attributes as you suggest and setting `services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol()` in my startup but the snake_cased properties still end up as null when they reach the hub